# Checking serial ports by script

Tags: linux, scripting, serial-port

I wanted to check available serial ports. How the script should like if I want to :

1. Check available devices from ttyUSBx
2. If anyone device is plugged -> run first program
3. After that, if plugged devices are more than 1 run second program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here's one that won't need `ls` or `grep`:

```
hasTTYUSB=0
moreThanOne=0
for i in /dev/ttyUSB* 
do
    if [ "$hasTTYUSB" -eq 1 ]; then 
        moreThanOne=1
    fi
    hasTTYUSB=1
done

if [ "$hasTTYUSB" -eq 1 ]; then
    # run first program here
fi
if [ "$moreThanOne" -eq 1 ]; then
    # run second program here
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a system call to ls /dev/ | grep tty and evaluate it's output.

```
serialPortList=$(ls /dev/ | grep tty)
for s in $serialPortList
do echo $s
done
```

now instead of the echo place what you want to do with the instance.

Comment: It's correctly returning my ttyUSB devices but how to make a condition in shell script?

Comment: please check out my edit.